# Refresh a static view controller

Tags: ios, swift, refresh, viewcontroller

To keep a complete design control over my project I am using a static `View Controller` for my main application window where I superpose labels and buttons over my images.

The issue is obviously that I now need to add a refresh control to the view and since I am not using a `Table View` I don't have the `Enable Refresh` option.

Is there any simple trick to implement a pull-to-refresh control or am I forced to reproduce my design to `Table View Cells`?

Comment: You are using tableviewcell without tableview?

Comment: For now it's just a View Controller with a view

Comment: You can use a scroll view and and a custom drag to refresh control

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes, it works

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a scroll view, here is what I did:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .valueChanged)
    scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}

@objc func doSomething(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("Hello World!")
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

I needed to extand the `scroll view` height to cover the pull extension at the top and at the bottom. I also added a background image to cover the white area that the pull created.

Now I need to write the code to update the data.